# How to show the length of a concatenated cycle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have been asked:

[image]

And I am stuck. I have thought about concatenating the permutation and analyzing the length of the result, but that is not leading anywhere.

Ideally I don't want the answer, just a hint as to how you can begin to show what the length of the resulting permutation is.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of an earlier question today, so probably homework. Hint: work some examples. What if $\gamma = (12345)$ and $\sigma = (234)$. Do a few more and you might/should be able to see a pattern. Describing the answer will show you that the length is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\vartheta:=\sigma\gamma\sigma^{-1}$ and express $\vartheta(\, \sigma(a_i)\,)$ for $i=1..n$. 
Then check what's $\vartheta(b)$ for $b\ne \sigma(a_i)$.